# merrging two arrays at specific date if both date matched

Tags: php

I am merging the two arrays at particular date. If both array have same date then it will merge the array & plot that array on the graph. But problem is that it is merging the array & appending the bar at the start of the bar only, but not at the specific date where the both date are equal.
for e.g.

```
array1 = (18/03/2013 => 10, 20-03-2013 => 6, 21-03-2013 => 10);
array2 = (20-03-2013 => 5);
```

. so it should append the bar at `20-03-2013` but actually it is appending the bar at the start only i.e. `18-03-2013`.

plz help me thanks in advance

hear is my code

```
   // gives the how many calls has came per day
$count = __Select("tbl_call_master","COUNT(DATE(date_time)) AS call_count ,  DATE(date_time)AS date ","WHERE DATE(date_time) BETWEEN      '$from_date' AND '$to_date' GROUP BY DATE(date_time) ");

$get_first_array=array(); //created the array to store the result


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($count))
{
    // daily records are been saved in record1[] array  
    $record1[]= array(
        $row['date'],
        $row['call_count']
    );

}
// gives the how many calls has came per day where status is WIP(work in progress) 
$wip=  __Select("tbl_call_master","COUNT(DATE(date_time)) AS  call_count , DATE(date_time) AS date ","WHERE status= 'WIP' AND DATE(date_time) BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date' GROUP BY DATE(date_time) ");

while($row= mysql_fetch_array($wip))
{
    //daily records are been saved in wiprecord[] array 
    $wiprecord[]= array(
        $row['date'],
        $row['call_count']
    );

}
$chk=0;
// foreach runs till the records are there  
foreach ( $record1 as  $key=> $value ) { 

// it will $chk is 1 if
     if($chk==1){ 
         $get_first_array[$key] =  $record1[$key]; //this record1 is gets transfer in another array which  i am going to show in graph
     }
//foreach runs till the wiprecords are there    
foreach ( $wiprecord as  $key=> $value1) {


end($wiprecord);// it will give the last index of wiprecord

    $last=key($wiprecord); // last index is stored in last variable
    if($key==$last ){ // if key is last then it will make the $chk to 1
        $chk=1;
    }
    if($value[0] == $value1[0] ) // checks whether date of record1 & date of wiprecord equals then it will enter in the condition
    {
        array_push($record1[$key], $wiprecord[$key][1]); // this will put the contents in record1[]
        $get_first_array[$key] = $record1[$key]; // this record1 is gets transfer in another array
        print_r( $get_first_array[$key]);   
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: too complex to understand...!!! Can you pls add comments!

Comment: ok now plz check it i have made the changes

Comment: You are using `$key` for both the `foreach`! are you sure that you are not using value of `$key` from parent `foreach($record1 as  $key=> $value)` inside nested `foreach($wiprecord as  $key=> $value1)` ???

Comment: ohh thanks sir problem solved thank you very much i have just changed the $key to $key1 where ever it was $key in nested foreach

Comment: kewl just now I figured it out too... :)

Comment: sir i just need 1 more help right now my graph is showing records of that date only on which are available but i wanted if record is not there then i have to show the 00 in graph i.e. array value to zero

Comment: I am trying it... U also try to achieve it...

Comment: I got the solution but just one doubt. I'll take the e.g that's give on the top. `18-03-2013` is present in `array1` but not in `array2`. So `$get_first_array[0] = array(0=>'18-03-2013',1=>10,2=>0);` (**or**) `$get_first_array[0] = array(0=>'18-03-2013',1=>0,2=>0);`. I mean should I make both the values 0 or only the value that's not present in `wip`? I hope I am clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made changes to your code:

1. Removed `$chk` and the if condition.
2. Added new variable `$date_is_matching`.
3. Reduced the complexity of the code.

Replace `$chk=0;` till `foreach($record1 as  $key=> $value){}//Opening to closing` with following:

```
$date_is_matching=0; 
//If date in $record1 is present in $wiprecord set $date_is_matching as 1.
foreach ( $record1 as  $key=>$value ) {
    foreach ($wiprecord as  $key1=> $value1) {
        if($value[0] == $value1[0]) {
            $date_is_matching=1;
            array_push($record1[$key], $wiprecord[$key1][1]);
        }
    }
    if($date_is_matching!=1) {
        array_push($record1[$key], 0);
    }
    $get_first_array[$key] =  $record1[$key];
    $date_is_matching=0;
} //But now $get_first_array = $record1;
```

This is how I've visualized your problem and solution: [link](http://elavarasanlee.koding.com/arrays.php)

---

**Update**:

```
$fill_date = array(); //New variable for adding missed dates and values(0).
for($i=0;$i<count($get_first_array)-1;$i++){
    $j = $i+1;
    $diff[$i] = GetDays($get_first_array[$i][0], $get_first_array[$i+1][0]); //Gets the dates between the two.
    if(!empty($diff[$i]) && is_array($diff[$i])) {
        foreach($diff[$i] as $date) {
            $fill_date[] = array(0=>$date,1=>0,2=>0); //Push the date and values
        }
    }
}
$get_first_array = array_merge($get_first_array,$fill_date); //Merge with the final array.
var_dump($get_first_array);
```

**Function GetDays()**:

```
function GetDays($sStartDate, $sEndDate) {
  // Firstly, format the provided dates. This function works best with YYYY-MM-DD
  // but other date formats will work thanks to strtotime().
  $sStartDate = strtotime($sStartDate);
  $sEndDate = strtotime($sEndDate);

  // If $sStartDate is bigger than $sEndDate, Then swap $sStartDate and $sEndDate
  if($sStartDate>$sEndDate) {
      $ttime = $sStartDate;
      $sStartDate = $sEndDate;
      $sEndDate = $ttime;
  }

  $sStartDate = gmdate("Y-m-d", $sStartDate);
  $sEndDate = gmdate("Y-m-d", $sEndDate);

  // Start the variable off with the start date
  //$aDays[] = $sStartDate;

  // Set a 'temp' variable, sCurrentDate, with the start date - before beginning the loop
  $sCurrentDate = $sStartDate;

  // While the current date is less than the end date
  while($sCurrentDate < $sEndDate){
    // Add a day to the current date
    $sCurrentDate = gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($sCurrentDate)));
    // Add this new day to the aDays array
    if($sCurrentDate != $sEndDate)
        $aDays[] = $sCurrentDate;
  }

  // Once the loop has finished, return the array of days.
  return $aDays;
}
```

---

**Input arrays**:

```
$record1 = array(0 => array(0=>'2013-03-18',1=>10), 
                 1 => array(0=>'2013-03-20',1=>6), 
                 2 => array(0=>'2013-03-21',1=>10), 
                 3=>array(0=>'2013-03-24',1=>10));

$wiprecord = array(0 => array(0=>'2013-03-20',1=>5), 
                   1 => array(0=>'2013-03-21',1=>5));
```

**Output array**:

```
$get_first_array = array ( 0 => array ( 0 => 2013-03-18 1 => 10 2 => 0 )
                           1 => array ( 0 => 2013-03-20 1 => 6 2 => 5 )
                           2 => array ( 0 => 2013-03-21 1 => 10 2 => 5 )
                           3 => array ( 0 => 2013-03-24 1 => 10 2 => 0 )
                           4 => array ( 0 => 2013-03-19 1 => 0 2 => 0 )
                           5 => array ( 0 => 2013-03-22 1 => 0 2 => 0 )
                           6 => array ( 0 => 2013-03-23 1 => 0 2 => 0 ) ) ;
```

Comment: sir this code has work but it worked for nested foreach actually i want it should work for outer foreach that is on whichever date the value is not there then it shoul represent that date with zero value. for e.g 18/03/2013, 20/03/2013, 23/03/2013 has the value so it will so that on this date this much is value, but i also want to represent that 19/03/2013=0, 21/03/2013=0, 22/03/2013=0 in array

Comment: I'll try that... Pls stop calling me sir. call me lee or elavarasan lee

Comment: Hi @swapnil: I got the answer. What's d format in which you are getting the date from db??? `dd-mm-yyy` format or `yyyy-mm-dd` format???

Comment: Hi @lee  its $from_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($from_date));
 $to_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($to_date));

Comment: hi @lee whats the solution i have to use for loop from the date range or what

Comment: no actually i am also trying i just thought that we have to use forloop

Comment: Ya I found a function from [here](http://edrackham.com/php/get-days-between-two-dates-using-php/) That can return dates in-between date1 and date2. I slightly modified it... I'll paste that function in my answer update...

Comment: Using the value that it returns U've to run the for loop and fill the empty dates...

Comment: so @lee the function which u have given in that in side the while loop i have to paste my code

Comment: @lee in that getDays() function  did i have to make any changes

Comment: @swapnil: yup... Just after the end of foreach in your code, paste the update followed by the function.

Comment: @lee yes it is returning nothing

Comment: `$from_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($from_date)); $to_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($to_date));` This is the format in which you are storing date in your array???

Comment: If you are passing strtotime values to `GetDays()` function, comment `$sStartDate = strtotime($sStartDate); $sEndDate = strtotime($sEndDate);` these two lines in `GetDays()` function.

Comment: @lee it has came but it is in some string format that is not representing in graph of phplot

Comment: the array format of var_dump is   array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "2013-04-04" [1]=> string(2) "26" [2]=> int(0) } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "2013-04-05" [1]=> string(1) "5" [2]=> int(0) } [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "2013-04-08" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(0) } }  still it is not giving the date which are missing

Comment: what's the actual array format you are using to plot the graph??? Update the format in your question...

Comment: Its having only years...!!! You want it for date also right??? `$data = array(
  array('2001',  60,  35,  20),
  array('2002',  65,  30,  30),
  array('2003',  70,  25,  40),
  array('2004',  72,  20,  60),
  array('2005',  75,  15,  70),
  array('2006',  77,  10,  80),
  array('2007',  80,   5,  90),
  array('2008',  85,   4,  95),
  array('2009',  90,   3,  98),
);`

Comment: this one is just e.g in which format the phplot takes the value

Comment: @lee in my date picker i have selected the date from 04/04/2013 to 08/04/2013 so the array is coming like that  array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "2013-04-04" [1]=> string(2) "26" [2]=> int(0) } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "2013-04-05" [1]=> string(1) "5" [2]=> int(0) } [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "2013-04-08" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> int(0) } } still it is not giving the date which are missing i.e. 06 & 07/04/2013

Comment: @swapnil: I've updated input and output arrays. check it and let me know if I am using right format...

Comment: @lee ok i will check it if i am doing something wrong or let me check it again anyway thanks for your time & thanks for helping me. if i m getting any problem then i will ask you. thanks once again

Comment: @lee hiiiii can i get ur email id beause i want to contact u

Comment: @lee actully right now i m doing login with fb so when i click on the login FB it redirects to fb home page but after putting the usernae & password & when i click login button it shows the configration error like this : Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.